# how to Unregister ContentObserver on AppWidgetProvider's-OnDisabled()

Tags: android, android-appwidget

in my appWidget I register some ContentObservers' in the OnEnabled() method.

so I've been told that I should unregister my ContentObserver's in the OnDisabled() method of my widget.

as far as I know, the only way to do so is by context.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);

the problem is: How do I save a pointer to the ContentObserver that I've registered in the OnEnabled() method, in order to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your widget start a Service and have the service register the ContentObservers. The Service can then push updates to the widget in response to notifications received by the ContentObservers.

Comment: Can you clarify how it's should be done? In particular, how do I save the ContentObserbers in order to unregister them in the OnDisabled() method? Can you explain some about Services? and how do I use them?

Comment: If you go that route you would not register/register the widget as an observer. You'd create a service that registers itself as a content observer and then pushes updates to your widget when it gets notifications. An example of a service pushing updates to a widget: http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/WordWidget.java. There is a lot of material available on services, including the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html